# Settings of the input files outside the bash script

Tags: bash

I'm dealing with the bash script which do sequence of the operation for set of the files each of which are loaded to the script using for loop

```
# run script.sh
script=./
for pdb in ${script}/workdir/*.pdb; do
   #some operations
done
```

Are there any possibilities to define the workdir (where all input pdb files are located) outside the script by means of some flag provided to the script file from the shell?

```
# run script.sh -r <path_to_the_work_dir>
```

what modification should be provided to the body of the script (i guess to the for loop)?
What are the general method to move some variables outside the script (to some flags provided with the script.sh file) in Bash?

Thanks for help,

James

Comment: You can pass arguments to your script. Those arguments are available as positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc. You can do anything you want with those.

Answer (score 0):

define workdir=$1 before it is called in the function. If more variables are need define them consecutively: var2=$2 , var3=$3

When calling the function from outside just give the path.

```
# run script.sh
workdir=$1
script=./
for pdb in ${script}/${workdir}/*.pdb; do
   #some operations
done
```

CALL:
one variable (as you wanted):

```
script.sh /home/lalal/functions/lalsl/
```

additional variables if needed:

```
script.sh /home/lalal/functions/lalsl/ var2 var3
```

Comment: @James Starlight if the answer worked for you please accept it at the left of it